# I just burned my bag of holding. Did the thing in it die?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In my campaign I had a bag of holding with a live creature inside of it. I poured oil on the bag and lit it with flint and steel, and let it burn up. Did the creature inside it die?

I don’t know if any of this matters but I might as well just put it down just in case. The only thing inside the bag was the creature and some ethereal water. When I burnt it it left a pile of ashes.

Answer (score 49):

### The creature is probably alive

Keep in mind that the [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) is resistant to fire damage:

> a magic item is at least as durable as a regular item of its kind. Most magic items, other than potions and scrolls, have resistance to all damage.

However it's hardly fireproof, since nothing in the rules says it can't be burned.

If the bag is destroyed, its contents are "scattered in the Astral Plane" (and probably lost):

> If the bag is overloaded, pierced, or torn, it ruptures and is destroyed, and its contents are scattered in the Astral Plane.

But the important thing is, breathing creatures suffocate inside the bag:

> Breathing creatures inside the bag can survive up to a number of minutes equal to 10 divided by the number of creatures (minimum 1 minute), after which time they begin to suffocate.

So *if* the creature survived inside the bag, it is now somewhere in the Astral Plane.

Comment: Could I not "stuff" a large amount of oxygen into the bag? And the carbon dioxide would have plenty of space too.

Comment: @MechMK1 this is what you should ask your DM about.

Comment: @MechMK1 that's the oxygen that allows breathing creatures to survive up to 10 minutes inside the bag in the first place.

Comment: Just as a side note, if it's in Ravenloft, then the stuff in the bag gets scattered across the domain rather than escaping to the Astral.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym and Mists would be probably kind enough to bring pissed off creature right at your doorstep when you least expect it.